# Magento auto inserting html code after body tag

Tags: html, magento, tags

iám trying to solve a problem that appear 1 month ago.

One magento store that i develop, in some product pages, maybe the javascript is auto inserting a period [.] before doctype tag at top of the page.

See this [link](http://www.comandoadistancia.com/ditec-gol4c.html)

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem. Can´t figure it.

Answer (score 0):

I hoped that was so easy... I see that a period is beeing added but isnt at top of the code. It somewhere else... Still debugging all the files.

Comment: Fixed... The period was in an extension file.